# Is it Valid to Use HTTP DELETE Request to Save Data and HTTP GET Request to Delete Data in Express.js?

Tags: express, http

Is it possible to use a DELETE request to save data and a GET request to delete data in an Express.js server?
For example, suppose I have an Express.js API that allows users to create and delete notes. Instead of using app.post to create a new note and app.delete to delete a note, can I use app.delete to create a new note and app.get to delete a note?
Here's an example of what the code might look like:

```
app.delete('/notes', (req, res) => {
  // Get the data from the request body
  const noteData = req.body;

  // Save the data to a database or file system
  // ...

  // Send a response to the client
  res.send('Note saved successfully');
});

app.get('/notes/:id', (req, res) => {
  // Get the ID of the note to delete
  const noteId = req.params.id;

  // Delete the note from the database or file system
  // ...

  // Send a response to the client
  res.send('Note deleted successfully');
});
```

Is this a valid approach, or should I stick to using app.post and app.delete for creating and deleting notes, respectively?